# Can you loop through an api endpoint? date data for example

Tags: reactjs, axios

I made a little project that renders a football league of your choice and then the standings for that year plus the overall points won. But now let's say I would like to display in one render the 10-year history of the said league to see who has won the most points. How can I manipulate the endpoint of this API :

[https://api-football-standings.azharimm.site/leagues/${selectedLeague}/standings?season=2011](https://api-football-standings.azharimm.site/leagues/$%7BselectedLeague%7D/standings?season=2011)

so let's say from 2011 till 2021. What is this process called?
Thank you in advance,
The code is below:

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {TailSpin} from "react-loader-spinner";



    const Standings = () => {
    
        const [data,setData] = useState([]);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        const [selectedLeague,setSelectedLeague] = useState('eng.1');
    
    
        useEffect(()=> {
            setLoading(true);
            axios(
            `https://api-football-standings.azharimm.site/leagues/${selectedLeague}/standings?season=2011`
            ).then(res=> {
            console.log(res.data.data.standings);
            setData(res.data.data.standings);
        } ).catch(err => console.log(err))
           .finally(() => setLoading(false));
    
        },[selectedLeague]);
    
    
        return (
        <div className="standings-container"> 
        <div className="select-container">
        <select
              name="select-league"
              id="select-league"
              defaultValue={selectedLeague}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedLeague(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="arg.1">Argentine Liga Profesional de Fútbol</option>
              <option value="aus.1">Australian A-League</option>
              <option value="bra.1">Brazilian Serie A</option>
              <option value="chn.1">Chinese Super League</option>
              <option value="ned.1">Dutch Eredivisie</option>
              <option value="eng.1">English Premier League</option>
              <option value="fra.1">French Ligue 1</option>
              <option value="ger.1">German Bundesliga</option>
              <option value="idn.1">Indonesian Liga 1</option>
              <option value="ita.1">Italian Serie A</option>
              <option value="jpn.1">Japanese J League</option>
              <option value="mys1">Malaysian Super League</option>
              <option value="mex.1">Mexican Liga BBVA MX</option>
              <option value="por.1">Portuguese Liga</option>
              <option value="rus.1">Russian Premier League</option>
              <option value="sgp.1">Singaporean Premier League</option>
              <option value="esp.1">Spanish Primera División</option>
              <option value="tha.1">Thai Premier League</option>
              <option value="tur.1">Turkish Super Lig</option>
              <option value="uga.1">Ugandan Super League</option>
            </select>
            
        </div>
        <div className="standing-results">
            { loading ? <TailSpin color="#00BFFF" height={80} width={80} /> :
            data.map((data, index) => (
                <div key={data.team.id} className="standing-info">
                <h1>
                    <span>{`${index+1}.`} <img src={data.team.logos[0].href} alt="#"/></span>
                    {data.team.shortDisplayName}
                    {JSON.stringify(data.stats[6].value)}
                    
                   
                    
                </h1>
                     </div>
    
            ))
    }
            
            
        </div>
        
        </div>
        );
    };
    
    
    export default Standings;
```